# Function code after for loop doesn't get executed ever

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to create a registration form and validate input fields using javascript, but I'm having difficulties after the for loop executes...

```
function checkValidation1() {

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {

        if($("#"+elem[i].id).val()=="") {
            $("#"+elem[i].id+"error").html("<img src='images/exclamationsmall.png' title='"+elem[i].name+" should not be blank'>");               

        } else if(elem[i].name=="email") {
            var emailReg = /^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/;

            if(!emailReg.test($("#"+elem[i].id).val())) {                        
                $("#"+elem[i].id+"error").html("<img src='images/exclamationsmall.png' title='"+elem[i].name+" is invalid'>");
            }
        } else {
            $("#"+elem[i].id+"error").html("");
        }
    } 
    alert("fasfasfasfasfasf");
}
```

The `alert` doesn't execute for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Luckily, if it is truly throwing an error, then you don't have to find it yourself. Debugging tools like the webkit dev tools or firebug will tell you exactly where the error is.

Comment: Did you ever call the function?

Comment: Can you show us how this code is executed? Where is checkValidation1 called? Is it `onSubmit`? Is there a reason you are mixing JQuery and native `document` methods?

Comment: @maxedison:firebug doesnot throw any error

Comment: @Neal: I called the function on button click.

Comment: @NT3RP: no particular reason of mixing JQuery And native, I called the function on button click , and the function works fine but somehow code after the for loop doesn't execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that all of your `input` elements actually have an `id` attribute. Otherwise this line:

```
if ($("#" + elem[i].id).val() == "") {
```

...will result in an expression containing only an octothorpe -- `$("#")` -- and the following error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

...which ultimately prevents the code from reaching the `alert`.

Comment: thanx , u were right , it was trying to get value from radio buttons :P.. which didnt have any value